# Why are different strings, which differ only in case, the same in SQL Server version 15.0.4033.1?

Tags: sql-server

When I use this code as a test:

```
declare @s1 varchar(100) set @s1 = 'AABA/2AA2AAA6YBAAc'
declare @s2 varchar(100) set @s2 = 'AABA/2AA2AAA6YBAAC'
IF
@s1=@s2
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Same'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not Same'
END
```

The result is 'Same'. Which to me sounds strange because s1 and s2 is different (see the last character c and C).

Why does SQL Server tell me they are the same?

Answer (score 2):

[Collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support). You are clearly using a case insensitive collations, therefore uppercase and lowercase letters are treated as the same for comparison operations. If you don't want different case values to appear the same, use a case sensitive collation.

For example, in the below, I change the collation of the variable `@s2` in the `IF`. If this was a table, you may want to change the definition of the column:

```sql
DECLARE @s1 varchar(100);
SET @s1 = 'AABA/2AA2AAA6YBAAc' 
DECLARE @s2 varchar(100);
SET @s2 = 'AABA/2AA2AAA6YBAAC'
IF @s1=@s2 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS BEGIN
    PRINT 'Same'
END ELSE BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not Same'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the collation.

To know which collation is in your database context, query :

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation')
```

CI indicate Case Insensitive.

Comment: The concept of COLLATION came from standard SQL since 1986 and refers to case (CI/CS) or diacritics sensitivity (AS/ASI - accents, ligatures...), wide of characters and some more features for some national languages (kanatypes for instance while using japanese alphabet)... MS SQL Sever has about 5000 different collations.

Comment: We're at over 5,500 now in SQL Server 2019; there were a lot added due to the new UTF8 collations.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because its case insensitive, You can try this simple approach to achieve your requirement by the below code :

```
declare @s1 varchar(100) set @s1 = 'AABA/2AA2AAA6YBAAc'
declare @s2 varchar(100) set @s2 = 'AABA/2AA2AAA6YBAAC'
IF HASHBYTES('sha1', @s1)=HASHBYTES('sha1', @s2)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Same'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not Same'
END
```

This code uses Hashbytes for this.

Comment: It would be more semantic to use a binary collation rather than using `HASHBYTES` to perform binary matching

Comment: More clear will be : IF (a)s1 = (a)s2 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS